# Giving access to enter key for textarea in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<td>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="1" style="padding: 10px;margin-left: 12px;border-radius: 10px; margin-right: 0px; width: 430px;"></textarea>
    <td style="padding-left:0px">
        <a title="Send" id="sendButtonId" onclick="return commentsByUser(this)" class="fa fa-location-arrow" href="#"></a>
    </td>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
```

I have the comment section in my application,I am using this code to get the comment but i am not able comment on entering 'enter' key from keyboard,how to give access for enter key

Comment: _Not able to enter comment on entering `enter` key_? What do you mean by that??

Answer (score 1):

You must bind `keypress` event to your `input`/`textarea`

```
$('textarea#message').bind('keypress',function (event){
  if (event.keyCode === 13){
    $('#sendButtonId').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Comment: Instead of `trigger('click');` you can execute your function to add comment. This was only an example

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit_on_enter').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            this.form.submit();
            return false;
         }
    });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<form action="path_to_the_action">
  <input class="submit_on_enter" onclick="return commentsByUser(this)">
</form>
```

Comment: I could not see the result in snippet

Comment: This will not trigger his commentsByUser() function.. he doesn't even seem to have a form in this code..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        alert('Enter key pressed');
        $('#sendButtonId').trigger('click');
    }
});

$('#sendButtonId').click(function(e) {
   // call ur function here...
});
```